# Select dependiente en Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas tengo que hacer un select dependiente y me he quedado cerca de completarlo, pero no se como rellenar el siguiente select con la info que traigo de la query.

**Select categorías**:
 Según lo que seleccione en este me tiene que sacar las sbucategorias que están en esa categoría.

```
<select class="form-control formNuevo" name="categoria" id="categoria">
    <option value=""> Selecciona una categoría </option> 
        @foreach ($categorias as $cat)
           <option value="{{ $cat->amigable }}"> {{ $cat->nombre }} </option> 
        @endforeach
</select>
```

**Select subcategoria**:
 Aquí es donde cargaremos las subcategorías que estén en esa categoría

```
<select class="form-control formNuevo" name="subcategoria" id='subcategoria'>
    <option value=""> Selecciona una subcategoría </option> 
</select>
```

**Ruta**

```
Route::get('admin/productos/select_category/{categoria}', 'AdminController@sacaSub');
```

**Controller**

```
public function sacaSub($categoria)
    {
        $subCate = Subcategoria::where('categoria', $categoria)->get();
        return with(["subCate" => $subCate]);
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#categoria').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var categoria = e.target.value;
        
        $.get('select_category/' + categoria,function(data) {
        
        $('#subcategoria').empty();
        $('#subcategoria').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true"></option>');
        
    })
    });
```

Consigo llevarme la id y hacer la query, pero no se como devolver las subcategorías a la vista y al javaScript. Dado que serán más de una subcategoria la que hay en cada categoría supongo que tendrá que ser algún foreach. Pero aquí me quede no se como avanzar.

Comment: si le das un `console.log(data);` notaras que es un arreglo asi que toca recorrerlo con un loop y vas imprimiendo los options por cada valor!

Comment: Me puedes guiar un poco más @Bryro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien lo he solucionado así, espero sea la forma correcta.

```
$('#categoria').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var categoria = e.target.value;
        
        $.get('select_category/' + categoria,function(data) {
        
        $('#subcategoria').empty();
        
        $.each(data, function(fetch, subCate){
            console.log(data);
            for(i = 0; i < subCate.length; i++){
            $('#subcategoria').append('<option value="'+ subCate[i].sAmigable +'">'+ subCate[i].nombre +'</option>');
            }
        })
     })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto mi solución, sólo javascript, sin jquery, lo tengo hecho con especialidades médicas y doctores, al seleccionar una especialidad te muestra los doctores correspondientes, tendrías que adaptarlo a tu caso:

Esto es el código a ejecutar cuando selecciona una especialidad (getDoctors), si hay doctores cargados toma el lenght y los borra uno por uno. Luego con el id de la especialidad recupero de la BD los doctores, el select doctor_id lo asigno a una variable doctors y con el último for asigno uno por uno los doctores de esa especialidad:

```
            var doctors = document.getElementById("doctor_id");
            for (let i = doctors.options.length; i >= 0; i--) {
              doctors.remove(i);
            }
            var id = document.getElementById('specialty_id').value;
            axios.post('/getDoctors/'+id)
              .then((resp)=>{
                var doctors = document.getElementById("doctor_id");
                for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(resp.data).length; i++) {
                  var option = document.createElement('option');
                  option.value = resp.data[i].id;
                  option.text = resp.data[i].apeynom;
                  doctors.appendChild(option);
                }
              })
              .catch(function (error) {console.log(error);})
```

En el controller traigo los doctores con esta función, busca todos los que coinciden con el $id enviado:

```
public function getDoctors($id)
{
  $doctors = DB::table('doctors')->where('specialty_id', '=', $id)->get();
  return $doctors;
}
```

La ruta post para llamar a ese método getDoctors es esta, el middleware('auth') podés quitarlo si no es necesario estar logueado en tu aplicación:

```
Route::post('/getDoctors/{id}', 'DoctorController@getDoctors')
              ->middleware('auth')
              ->name('getDoctors');
```

En la vista estos son los select, primero las especialidades, luego los doctores, así:

```
          <select class="custom-select mb-1" name="specialty_id" id="specialty_id" onchange="getDoctors()">
            <option value="0" selected>Seleccione Especialidad</option>
            @foreach($specialties as $specialty)
              <option value="{{ $specialty->id }}">
                  {{ $specialty->descripcion }}
              </option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
          <select class="custom-select" name="doctor_id" id="doctor_id">
            <option value="0" selected>Seleccione Profesional</option>
            @foreach($doctors as $doctor)
              <option value="{{ $doctor->id }}">
                  {{ $doctor->apeynom }}
              </option>
            @endforeach
          </select>
```

Y por último, lo primero, como envío los arreglos a la vista al inicio:

```
$specialties = DB::table('specialties')
                            ->where('vigente', '=', 1)
                            ->orderBy('descripcion','asc')
                            ->get();
$doctors = DB::table('doctors')->where('id', '=', 0)->get();
```

Tengo un campo para filtrar las especialidades vigentes y ordeno por el nombre de la especialidad, en Doctors empiezo buscando id = 0 para que el arreglo inicie vacío, se llenará cuando seleccione alguna especialidad, espero que te sume algo, saludos!

Comment: Estás llevando al OP de JQuery a JS puro, entonces para que sea enriquecedora la respuesta deberías explicarle tu código

Comment: Ok, hace poco he empezado a responder por acá y voy aprendiendo, ahí lo edito, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#categoria').on('change', function(e){
    console.log(e);
    var categoria = e.target.value;
    
    $.get('select_category/' + categoria,function(data) {
    
    $('#subcategoria').empty();
    
    $.each(data, function(fetch, subCate){
        console.log(data);
        for(i = 0; i < subCate.length; i++){
        $('#subcategoria').append('<option value="'+ subCate[i].sAmigable +'">'+ subCate[i].nombre +'</option>');
        }
    })
 })
});
```

Comment: Si vas a copiar la [respuesta aceptada](/a/365947), al menos explica su funcionamiento. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.